# ASP MVC binding two controls to one field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my view model I have a field. This field can be selected from a drop down list or entered in a textbox. I have two radio buttons which allows to select between drop and textbox.

```
<div class="frm_row" id="contractorRow">
    @Html.RadioButton("IsContractorNew", "false", true)
    @Html.Label(@Resources.SomeLabels.Existing)
    @Html.RadioButton("IsContractorNew", "true", false)
    @Html.Label(@Resources.SomeLabels.New)
    <div class="frm_row_input" id="contractorDropDownList">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CONTRACTOR, Model.Contractors)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CONTRACTOR)
    </div>
    <div class="frm_row_input" id="contractorTextBox" style="display: none;">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CONTRACTOR)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CONTRACTOR)
    </div>
</div>
```

I prepared a javascript code for hiding, showing and clearing controls while selecting radio buttons. The problem is - field is bound only to the first control (drop down list).

EDIT:

I solved this problem by creating one hidden field and scripting whole logic to bind active control with it and therefore with the model. Anyway if anyone knows simpler solution, please post it.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but for those dealing with this issue, here's a solution:

**Explanation**

When a form is submitted, input elements are bound to the model by their name attribute.  Let's say you use HTML helpers to generate your form, and you generate two input fields which bind to the same property on the model.  When rendered to the DOM, they both have the same name attribute.

```
<input name="Passport.BirthPlace" id="birthPlaceDropDown" ... >
<input name="Passport.BirthPlace" id="birthPlaceInfoTextbox" ... >
```

When the form is submitted, it will bind the **first** (in the DOM) input it finds to Passport.BirthPlace

**A Solution**

The quick and easy way to fix this is to use JQuery to change the name of the field you don't want bound on submit.  For me, I use a checkbox to toggle which field shows.  When the checkbox changes, I hide one control, change its name attribute, and show the other one (and change it's name attribute to Passport.BirthPlace)  It looks like this, basically:

First, I run this on document ready

```
$('#birthPlaceInfoTextbox').attr('name', 'nosubmit'); // Change name to avoid binding on inactive element
```

Then, I create a listener for my checkbox which toggles which control should be bound:

```
$('#notBornUSCheckbox').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        // Not born us was checked, hide state dropdown and show freeform text box
        $('#stateDropDownSection').addClass('d-none'); // Hide drop down
        $('#birthPlaceDropDown').attr('name', 'nosubmit');  // Change name to something other than Passport.BirthPlace
        $('#birthPlaceInfoTextbox').attr('name', 'Passport.BirthPlace'); // Set this one to be bound to the model
        $('#stateTextboxSection').removeClass('d-none'); // Show the textbox field
    } else { // Opposite of above lines
        $('#stateDropDownSection').removeClass('d-none');
        $('#stateTextboxSection').addClass('d-none');
        $('#birthPlaceInfoTextbox').attr('name', 'nosubmit');
        $('#birthPlaceDropDown').attr('name', 'Passport.BirthPlace');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you... dealing with this in 2021 haha

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Razor `@Html.TextBoxFor`... for your textbox, you could try using raw HTML e.g. `<input />`. Also, have your JavaScript code remove the other field from the DOM entirely when a radio button is clicked, before submitting the form.

Comment: Thank you. I've got different idea - I decided to put one hidden field for a model's field and bind it with drop down and textbox conditionally. Anyway I'm surprised it's so tough.